# Indexing HTML in Elasticsearch via python3

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, indexing, python-3.6

I am new to Elasticsearch. I have to index many HTML files via python3. I've seen many examples of adding info into Elasticsearch, but couldn't actually find anything appropriate for me. Can I index HTML files without extracting all their information in JSON format? I've seen some examples of indexing PDF to Elasticsearch via PHP using pipeline, but could not find something like this for python.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by index HTML files to Elasticsearch? What kind of information do you want to send to Elasticsearch?

Yes its definitely possible, but give a bit more details of what you want to be sending to Elasticsearch. (full HTML pages, only the name, certain information from HTML files, etc)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have to index full HTML pages.

Comment: @alexqrid Full html pages, as in contents of page, or title....or..? like tell me more then 1 sentence of what you want. Perhaps then i can help you ;)

Also perhaps short overview of what index is, and contents of index, so as in why you want to index HTML files (which to me says nothing really atm ).

Comment: I want to index all the content of many HTML files, and organize full-text search through that files. Like google search :) I have already known about html_strip analyzer in elasticsearch. I want to know are there anyway of indexing that files in elasticsearch without extracting the content of each file into  a field of elasticsearch:

Comment: I don't want do it like that:
{...
"title":"<title>Empire State Building - Wikipedia</title>"
"field": "<p>Demolition of the Waldorf–Astoria began in October 1929, and the foundation of the Empire State Building </p>"
...
}
May be I can somehow organize search without extracting the content of the file, just attaching the file like: 
{
"id": 1
"file": "my.html/path to my html"
"date":"2018.11.16"
}
And elastic will index and analyze it. Or I want too much from him?:))

Comment: Id say that if you want elastic to perform analysis on it you would need to ship some kind of information to elasticsearch aswell. not just paths since then you will need to perform analysis somewhere else, negating the use of elastic...


you could perhaps just ship all the information of the page to one variable, say "message", and then perform different queries from within elastic on this variable field...

Comment: Ok.Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score -1):

Here a sample of a class that might be handy for you..

```
#ELK credentials
ELK_HOST = "[hostname]"
ELK_USER = "[elastic_user]"
ELK_PASSWORD= "[elastic_password]"

HEADERS = {
    'host' : '[put hostname again if using redirects ;)]',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
}

class ElasticSearch():
    def __init__(self,host,user,password):
        self._host = host
        self._user = user
        self._password = password
        self._auth = (self._user, self._password)

    def update_index(self, index, data):
        endpoint = str(index)+"/doc/"
        uri = self._host +"/"+ endpoint
        _data = data
        _data = python_to_json(_data)
        response = requests.post(uri, headers=HEADERS, auth=self._auth,data=_data)


es = ElasticSeach(ELK_HOST,ELK_USER,ELK_PASSWORD);

#some random data
data = {"test1": 1, "test2" : 2}

#update index (if doesnt exist, it will create a new one)
es.update_index("testindex",data)
```

hope this will help you!